# Blender + Python

Tags: python, blender

```
import bpy 
    positions = (0,3,2) , (4,1,6) , (3,-5,1) , (3,10,1) , (1,8,1)
    start_pos =(0,0,0)
    ob = bpy.data.objects ["Sphere"]
    frame_num = 0 
     for position in positions:
         bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame_num)
         ob.location = position
         ob.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", index =-1)
         frame_num +=20
```

Can anyone help me realize the error and what part of the code is wrong I can't understand what is wrong

This is the error
'Python script failed, check the message in the system console'

Comment: well what does the console say?

Comment: PYTHON INTERACTIVE CONSOLE 3.7.0 (default, Aug 26 2018, 16:05:01) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

Command History:     Up/Down Arrow
Cursor:              Left/Right Home/End
Remove:              Backspace/Delete
Execute:             Enter
Autocomplete:        Ctrl-Space
Zoom:                Ctrl +/-, Ctrl-Wheel
Builtin Modules:     bpy, bpy.data, bpy.ops, bpy.props, bpy.types, bpy.context, bpy.utils, bgl, blf, mathutils
Convenience Imports: from mathutils import *; from math import *
Convenience Variables: C = bpy.context, D = bpy.data

Comment: Check the indentation of your code

Comment: i don't see an error in there

Comment: File "\Text", line 4
    start_pos=0,0,0)
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

location: <unknown location>:-1

Comment: @AnaBettencourt, check the indentation, you have extra leading whitespaces

Comment: I'm sorry i'm portuguese i don't understand what you mean, what is indentation

Comment: You can ask blender specific scripting questions at [blender.stackexchange](http://blender.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

The formatting used in a python script affects the way it is interpreted. You need to make sure that each block of code has matching indentation, which is normally set at four spaces per indentation.

There is a formal specification of how to format a python script, often referred to as [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#code-lay-out)

The correctly formatted version of your script should look like :-

```
import bpy 
positions = (0,3,2) , (4,1,6) , (3,-5,1) , (3,10,1) , (1,8,1)
start_pos =(0,0,0)
ob = bpy.data.objects ["Sphere"]
frame_num = 0 
for position in positions:
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame_num)
    ob.location = position
    ob.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", index =-1)
    frame_num +=20
```